# Erro de Visualização na Página com código PHP

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue ajudar-me a perceber o porquê de o código que está em baixo estar errado? Falta alguma parametrização para que este não apareça na página principal?

```
                <?php } if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
            ?>
            <div class="caption">Resultado do Login:</div>
            <div id="icon2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div id="result">
            <table width="100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><br />
                  <br />
            if ($error == "") {
            echo "Benvindo";
            echo "<a href="index.php">Click aqui para entrar.</a>";
            }
            else echo $error;
            ?&gt;
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  <br />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <?php }
            ?> </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o problema? O que seria "este não apareça na página principal"? O próprio código PHP está sendo exibido? Se sim, você está executando o arquivo em um servidor com suporte a PHP?

Comment: Adicionei uma fotogradia, em que demonstra o que aparece na página. Supostamente este campo deveria de estar oculto, para quando fizermos um Login errado ele voltar à página inicial.

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes sobre o problema, assim fica complicado ajudar.  Coloque na pergunta uma parte maior do código.

Comment: Já é possível ajudar desta forma?

Comment: Impossível dizer com certeza. Ainda a pergunta não faz sentido. Mas já percebi que você está utilizando aspas duplas dentro da *string* no PHP; isso quebra a *string* e gera o resultado inesperado. Tente alterar para aspas simples: `echo "<a href='...'>...</a>"` (perceba as aspas simples no `href` do link).

Comment: Tente isso: `if ($error == "") { echo "Benvindo <br/> <a href='index.php'>Click aqui para entrar.</a>";
            }`

Comment: Ainda não está funcionando.. eu vou colocar uma imagem mais nitida, pode ser que ajude.. o código é muito extenso para o poder colocar aqui

Comment: O problema que surge a seguir é que depois de fazer o login , a página não vai para a pretendida, mas se clicar onde diz "Click aqui para entrar.! aí já entra..

Comment: que começo é esse   `<?php }`

Answer (score 0):

Adicione as tags do php, `<?php` e `?>` para este trecho do código:

```
if ($error == "") {
 echo "Benvindo";
 echo "<a href="index.php">Click aqui para entrar.</a>";
}
 else echo $error;
```

Comment: O problema que surge a seguir é que depois de fazer o login , a página não vai para a pretendida, mas se clicar onde diz "Click aqui para entrar.! aí já entra..

Answer (score 0):

Estrutura do código está com um pequeno erro, o correto séria:

```
<?php } if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){ ?>
        <div class="caption">Resultado do Login:</div>
        <div id="icon2">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="result">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><br />
              <br />
       <?php
          if ($error == ""){
            echo "Benvindo";
            echo "<a href="index.php">Click aqui para entrar.</a>";
          }else
            echo $error;
        ?>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        </div>
```